# Flash AS3: Tween MC to MC on Frame to Frame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tween

I am trying to build a four frame animation in Flash CS3.
The background images (each being set to MovieClips) change on each frame, and I want to put a fade out/in transition on each of the MC's.
I can't seem to get this working properly though.
Here is the code I have:

```
if (currentFrame == 1) {
    var alphaTweenOut1:Tween = new Tween (image1, "alpha", Regular.easeOut, 100, 0, 1, true);
    var alphaTweenIn2:Tween = new Tween (image2, "alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0, 100, 3, true);
} else if (currentFrame == 2) {
    var alphaTweenOut2:Tween = new Tween (image2, "alpha", Regular.easeOut, 100, 0, 1, true);
    var alphaTweenIn3:Tween = new Tween (image3, "alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0, 100, 3, true);
} else if (currentFrame == 3) {
    var alphaTweenOut3:Tween = new Tween (image3, "alpha", Regular.easeOut, 100, 0, 1, true);
    var alphaTweenIn4:Tween = new Tween (image4, "alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0, 100, 3, true); 
} else {
    var alphaTweenOut4:Tween = new Tween (image4, "alpha", Regular.easeOut, 100, 0, 1, true);       
    var alphaTweenIn1:Tween = new Tween (image1, "alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0, 100, 3, true);
    //loop back to first frame (there is a 5th frame that is triggered on mouse events)
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a frame animation? I'm thinking you could pull off the same effect having the images added to the stage with their alphas all set to zero. Then using TweenLite for the transitions :)

Comment: I haven't used TweenLite before.  Is it difficult to figure out?  I actually think I just have figured out most of this problem on my own, I was having problems cause I'm also pausing the frames with a timer, and had these transitions in the wrong function.  In any case, my main reason for shying away from putting everything on 1 frame is that each frame has various buttons on it that are triggering different movies and whatnot.  Figured working with the stage would probably be easier.

Comment: I love TweenLite, light and easy to use: http://blog.greensock.com/tweenliteas3/ :)

Comment: Leon, I downloaded TweenLite, but I can't find any good documenation on anything I have to do in terms of setup. Is it really as simple as dropping the 'gs' folder inside the directory my flash file lives in? Do you know of any good tutorials in basic useage of TL? I just need 4 images to loop around (in 1 frame is fine), but I also need to be able to declare variables based on the currently active image (so if a user clicks 'watch video' while on image2, it plays video2). Any and all help is greatly appreciated.